# how to get a str from terminal and decode as gbk

Tags: python, input, terminal, character-encoding, decode

i need to get a str from terminal. Sometime, it's gbk, like:

```
\77\262\331\327\367
```

what i should do to get what the str really is.
if it's in code, it can be decode and print correctly.

```
inpt=b"\77\262\331\327\367"
print(inpt.decode("gbk"))

inpt=input("input: ")
print(inpt.decode("gbk"))
```

[image: code]
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

The [`input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. Hence, the `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` message is quite comprehensible.

You need to build a `bytes` object from that string. Here's my old-school (non-Pythonish) solution (the script produces some didactic and illustrative output):

```
inpt=b"\77\262\331\327\367"
print("\ninpt")
print(type(inpt),"\t",inpt )
print(type(inpt.decode("gbk")),"\t",inpt.decode("gbk"))

inps=r"\77\262\331\327\367" # instead of inps=input("input octals, \\ delimited: ")
print("\ninps")
print(type(inps),"\t",inps )

inpb=b''
for x in list(filter(None, inps.split("\\"))):
    inpb+=bytes.fromhex(hex(int(x,8)).replace('0x',''))

print("\ninpb")
print(type(inpb),"\t",inpb )
print(type(inpb.decode("gbk")),"\t",inpb.decode("gbk"))
```

**Output**: 61134038.py

> ```
> inpt
> <class 'bytes'>          b'?\xb2\xd9\xd7\xf7'
> <class 'str'>    ?操作
>
> inps
> <class 'str'>    \77\262\331\327\367
>
> inpb
> <class 'bytes'>          b'?\xb2\xd9\xd7\xf7'
> <class 'str'>    ?操作
> ```